# How to determine if NSManagedObjectID is permament?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to make sure that an NSManagedObject that I am working with has a permanent NSManagedObjectID. I know that it only is made permanent on [NSManagedObjectContext save:] or [NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]. However, before I save the context to get a permanent ID, is there a way to determine if an object has a permanent ID or not? That way I don't needlessly save the store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectID` has a `isTemporaryID` method that indicates whether the object ID is temporary, so you can check

```
BOOL isTemporary = [[myObject objectID] isTemporaryID];
```

However, I would just call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` for the objects in question because I *assume* that this does not cause additional overhead if the object IDs are already permanent.